# What is the advantage of using prototype in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

The following is my code:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
} 

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
```

Later, we can add a property to the person object as follows:

```
myFather.nationality = "English";
```

The same can be done using Prototype as follows:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
} 


Person.prototype.nationality = "English";
```

**Actual question:** Why should use prototype to property or function to object when we can do it as `myFather.nationality = "English";` ?

Please guide me.

Comment: prototype allow us to use function properties outside the method.